# ¿Es necesario tener la carpeta node_modules en cada proyecto?

Tags: nodejs

Sé que la carpeta `node_modules` tiene toda las dependencias y eso; pero mi pregunta se debe a que, estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Sass y otro proyecto diferente con Babel; y me he dado cuenta que ambos proyectos tienen una carpeta `node_modules`.

Además esas carpetas contienen algunos módulos similares. Entonces, **¿no seria mejor solo tener una carpeta node_modules, "de forma global"?** Como sabrán, esos módulos pesan bastante. Lo que estaba pensando hacer es poner todo mis proyectos en una sola carpeta y junto a estos poner `node_modules` y que sea compartido por todo los proyectos, **¿estaría bien?**

Comment: Si tienes una sola carpeta entonces no son distintos proyectos, es uno solo con distintos puntos de ejecución, lo cual te causará más dolores de cabeza que el problema de almacenamiento que planteas.

Comment: entonces ¿es normal tener ```node_modules``` en cada proyecto?

Comment: Hmmm, si tienes dos portátiles con windows 10, es normal que cada uno tenga todos los archivos de windows 10 duplicados? No te valdría con tenerlos en un único portátil? Y qué pasa si el otro portátil se apaga o se desconecta de la red? El que depende de él se queda inútil? Pues básicamente es lo mismo... podrías tener una carpeta única... si, y qué pasa si cambias la versión en uno y no en el otro? O decides mover el proyecto a otro sitio? Cada proyecto necesita sus versiones específicas, al final sería un lio inmantenible tener todo junto :)

Comment: Correcto, es lo normal en proyectos de NodeJS.

Comment: entonces supongo que cuando suba mi proyecto a GitHub  debo ignorar la carpeta```node_modules``` y solo subir lo necesario junto al archivo packages.json que controla las versiones de las dependencias; y cuando alguien quiera continuar mi proyecto, tendrá que correr ```npm install``` para que se le descargue ```node_modules``` con todo lo necesario, y podrá continuar el proyecto sin problemas ...?

Comment: @kraud correcto. No quieres subir todo lo que hay en node_modules.